# javascript how to get this.variable in callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

In the following customized class in javascript, in callback, why does this.obj have nothing but local variable obj has thing I want?  Thanks.

```
function ClassTest(director) {
  this.obj = {"test1": "test1"};
}

function test1(input, callback) {
  callback("success");
}

ClassTest.prototype.test = function() {
  var obj = this.obj;
  test1("niuniu",function(e){
    console.log(this.obj);  // undefined
    console.log(obj);  // this one has stuff
    });
}

// run 
new ClassTest().test()
```

Comment: Add `var that = this;` and then inside the callback you use `that` to refer to `this` :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the function inside `test1` is creating a new scope with different `this` context. Typical solutions are to `bind` or to cache `this`:

Binding:

```
test1("niuniu",function(e){
  console.log(this.obj);
}.bind(this));
```

Caching:

```
var self = this;
test1("niuniu",function(e){
  console.log(self.obj);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As for this line of code:

```
console.log(obj);  // this one has stuff
```

The reason it works has to do with how JavaScript closure works. The code defined in your anonymous function has access to all variables in its local scope as well as variables defined in encompassing scopes and therefore `obj` is available.    See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for more on closure.

The keyword `this` however, is a reference to the current scope. Because you are accessing `this.obj` from within the anonymous function, `this` refers to the anonymous function itself - which has no `obj` property defined. In the enclosing function, which is extending the `ClassTest` prototype, `this` refers to the current `ClassTest` object, which does have a `obj` property defined.