# Passing on object to a function inside a functioncall

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, parameters

I would like the function located in my ajax call to have access to the variable "this" in the scope it's being called from. I would like to avoid as much hard coding as possible and thus I have to ask for help. Here are some ideas though.

- add an optional parameter in the ajax function that will be sent as an argument in the callback call. It won't be pretty but it will surely work.
- Send the object reference with the ajax, receive it with php and send it back, and then access it through the response. This would spare the ajax function but pass the mess to the backend.

```js
// Working ajax function | The problem is below this
function ajax(protocol = "GET", url = "", callback = function(response){ console.log(response); }, data = null){
 
 // Build data
 var formData = null;
 if(data !== null){
  formData = new FormData();
  for(var instance in data){
   formData.append(instance, data[instance]);
  }
 }

 // Build essential ajax components
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open(protocol, url, true);
 
 // Check for state updates
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
   if(xhr.status === 200){
    callback(xhr.responseText);
   }
   else{
    callback("Error code: " + xhr.status);
   }
        }
 }

 // Send it!
 xhr.send(formData);
}



// My class
function MyClass(el){
  this.target = el;
  this.fetch(); // Call the fetch method
}
MyClass.prototype.fetch(){
  this; // "This" works perfectly in this scope as it refers to myInstance in this example
  
  
  ajax("POST", "target/path.php", function(response){
    var newEl = document.createElement("div");
    newEl.innerHTML = response;
    
    // HERE's THE RPOBLEM 
    this.target.appendChild(newEl); // "this" refers to the window object..
    
  }, {data: "data"});
}

var myTarget = document.getElementById("myTarget");
var myInstance = new MyClass(myTarget);
```

```html
<div id="myTarget"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript how to get this.variable in callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14670359/javascript-how-to-get-this-variable-in-callback-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple solutions for your issue

1) You can create a closure

```
MyClass.prototype.fetch(){
  this; // "This" works perfectly in this scope as it refers to myInstance in this example

  var that = this;

  ajax("POST", "target/path.php", function(response){
    var newEl = document.createElement("div");
    newEl.innerHTML = response;

    // HERE's THE RPOBLEM 
    that.target.appendChild(newEl); // "this" refers to the window object..

  }, {data: "data"});
}
```

2) You can use [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
MyClass.prototype.fetch(){
  this; // "This" works perfectly in this scope as it refers to myInstance in this example


  ajax("POST", "target/path.php",(function(response){
    var newEl = document.createElement("div");
    newEl.innerHTML = response;

    // HERE's THE RPOBLEM 
    this.target.appendChild(newEl); // "this" refers to the window object..

  }).bind(this), {data: "data"});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May store this:

```
var context = this;
```

Inside the callback, use context...
Your this is referring to window, as it is called by a window objects function (your ajax function).
By the way, your code is wrong (the prototype dec):

```
MyClass.prototype.fetch=function(){
 var context=this; // "This" works perfectly in this scope as it refers to myInstance in this example 
ajax("POST", "target/path.php", function(response){ 
var newEl = document.createElement("div");
 newEl.innerHTML = response; 
// HERE's NOT THE RPOBLEM   
context.target.appendChild(newEl); // "context" refers to the MyClass Object object..
 }, {data: "data"}); }
```

Comment: Thanks! I simplified my code without testing it, that's why the method was incorrect.